# How to keep increased content inside div

Tags: php, css, mysql

As you ses in the bit of code bellow I'm getting some information out of my database and manipulating how many characters in output by changing the number (17). The problem is that if I change from 17 to for example 50 the output goes outside of the div. How can I keep the outputted characters inside the div if I increase the number?

```
$shortUrlObj = shortUrl::loadByID($u);

<div class="services" style="margin: 1px;">
<h3><?php echo t("redirecting_to"); ?><br><?php echo $shortUrlObj->getFormattedLongUrl(17); ?></h3>

</div>
```

Comment: Try to add 'overflow: hidden' to div style

Comment: This appears to be a CSS / HTML question with nothing to do with mysql and almost nothing to do with PHP. Try to tag the technology which is most relevant to the issue, not just any technology that your application uses at some point. Then your question is more likely to be viewed by people who can provide relevant help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` so if a text is too long it will just be shortend by ...

```css
div   {
  max-width: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: #333 dashed 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Don't forget this one */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis">Very Long Text with ellipsis: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
<div>Very Long Text without ellipsis: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try this.

```
.services{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```